# A and B are real, symmetric and positive semi-definite matrices of the same order; is AB diagonalizable?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, positive-semidefinite

I've already proved this with B positive definite using the fact that $B^{-\frac{1}{2}}$ does exist and AB is similar to $A^{\frac{1}{2}}BA^{\frac{1}{2}}$, but since B is positive semi-definite I don't know if that is true. I also know that $A^{\frac{1}{2}}$ and $B^{\frac{1}{2}}$ are defined.

I´m trying to see that $A^{\frac{1}{2}}BA^{\frac{1}{2}}$ is similar to $A^{\frac{1}{2}}A^{\frac{1}{2}}B$, but i'm having problems with that.

Any hint would help, thanks!

Comment: I believe that A and B need to share a common basis in eigenvectors in order to be able to commute, and in general AB is only guaranteed to be diagonalizable if A and B commute.  Commute means AB=BA.

Comment: Are you sure that AB is guaranteed to be diagonalizable if A and B conmute? I'm not sure about that. Diagonalization is different than simultaneous diagonalization

Comment: Simultaneous diagonalization is a property on a set of of matrices, while the comment is about the single matrix $AB$.

Comment: Ok, I see, but I still thinking that the statement is true

Comment: The statement is true and proven in Corollary 2.3 in this article: https://reader.elsevier.com/reader/sd/pii/002437959190239S?token=6D0F50BB70575D120D81774C90B25337FC1A180C9721693CA64B6C81BCF09C5BDD1BA218CF8CC2FF49ABB47781E72E04

Comment: To the OP; when writing a conjecture, you should definitely report clearly this fact in the title and body of the text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By a change of orthonormal basis, we may assume that
$$
A=\pmatrix{A_{r\times r}'&0\\ 0&0_{(n-r)\times(n-r)}}
\text{ and } B=\pmatrix{B_{r\times r}'&\ast\\ \ast&B_2},
$$
where $A'$ is positive definite. Then, by performing another change of orthonormal basis (or by orthogonally diagonalising $B'$, followed by permuting the diagonal entries of $B'$), we may further assume that
$$
A=\pmatrix{A_1&X^T&0\\ X&A_2&0\\ 0&0&0}
\text{ and } B=\pmatrix{B_1&0&Y^T\\ 0&0&Z^T\\ Y&Z&B_2},
$$
where $A'=\pmatrix{A_1&X^T\\ X&A_2}$ and $B'=\pmatrix{B_1&0\\ 0&0}$, with $B_1$ being positive definite. However, since $B$ is positive semidefinite, the sub-block $Z$ must be zero. It follows that
$$
AB
=\pmatrix{A_1&X^T&0\\ X&A_2&0\\ 0&0&0}\pmatrix{B_1&0&Y^T\\ 0&0&0\\ Y&0&B_2}
=\pmatrix{A_1B_1&0&AY^T\\ XB_1&0&XY^T\\ 0&0&0}
$$
is similar to the positive semidefinite matrix $A_1^{1/2}B_1A_1^{1/2}\oplus0\oplus0$:
\begin{aligned}
&\pmatrix{A_1^{-1/2}&0&A_1^{-1/2}B_1^{-1}Y^T\\ -XA_1^{-1}&I&0\\ 0&0&I}
\pmatrix{A_1B_1&0&AY^T\\ XB_1&0&XY^T\\ 0&0&0}
\pmatrix{A_1^{1/2}&0&-B_1^{-1}Y^T\\ XA_1^{-1/2}&I&-XA_1^{-1}B_1^{-1}Y^T\\ 0&0&I}\\
&=\pmatrix{A_1^{1/2}B_1&0&A_1^{1/2}Y^T\\ 0&0&0\\ 0&0&0}
\pmatrix{A_1^{1/2}&0&-B_1^{-1}Y^T\\ XA_1^{-1/2}&I&-XA_1^{-1}B_1^{-1}Y^T\\ 0&0&I}\\
&=\pmatrix{A_1^{1/2}B_1A_1^{1/2}&0&0\\ 0&0&0\\ 0&0&0}.
\end{aligned}
Hence $AB$ is diagonalisable.

Comment: If you have time could you please explain the third tl last eq. line?

Comment: The choice of left and right hand side matrices in the line after "is similar to the positive semidefinite matrix".

Comment: Yes isn't that particular $A$ and $B$ we can assume  $A$ in the form you gave but $B$ may be different?

Comment: Never seen such thing what if $B$ is invertible no zeros in the diagonal? after your matrix products

Comment: @ToniMhax If $B$ is positive definite, the zero sub-blocks are empty.

Comment: Ok you should have put the unitaries you used, no one will know the final expressions $A$ and $B$ since it is two changement of basis. I am deleting the comments. Best

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't get who is $A_1$

Comment: @aalamo1 If $B_1$ is $k\times k$, $A_1$ is the leading principal $k\times k$ submatrix in $A'$. In other words, we partition $A'$ and $B'$ in the same way, and call the submatrix at the top left corner of $A'$ as $A_1$.

Answer (score 2):

**preliminaries**
$A^\frac{1}{2}BA^\frac{1}{2}$ is real symmetric positive semi-definite because
$\mathbf x^TA^\frac{1}{2}BA^\frac{1}{2}\mathbf x = \big\Vert B^\frac{1}{2}A^\frac{1}{2}\mathbf x\big\Vert_2^2\geq 0$ for any $\mathbf x \in \mathbb R^n$
we also know
$\text{trace}\Big(\big(A^\frac{1}{2}BA^\frac{1}{2}\big)^k\Big)= \text{trace}\Big(\big(AB\big)^k\Big)$
for all natural numbers $k$ so they have the same characteristic polynomials

$C:=A^\frac{1}{2}BA^\frac{1}{2}$
and for natural numbers $k$ we have the useful identity
$A^\frac{1}{2}C^k A^\frac{1}{2}B = (AB)^{k+1}=  (AB)(AB)^{k} $

since $C$ is diagonalizable over reals we proceed with a minimal polynomial argument

**main argument**
we have
$p(C) = \mathbf 0$
where $p$ is the minimal polynomial of $C$-- i.e. for this problem: $p$ is the characteristic polynomial of $C$ except there are no repeated roots. This implies

$\mathbf 0 =A^\frac{1}{2} p(C)A^\frac{1}{2}B =  AB\cdot p(AB)=g\big(AB\big)$

Thus the polynomial $g$ annihilates $(AB)$, and $g$ has no repeated roots, except possibly with the eigenvalue zero.

thus we know that for every distinct $\lambda \gt 0$ of $\big(AB\big)$ we have
$\text{geometric multiplicity}_{\text{of }\lambda}\big(AB\big)= \text{algebraic multiplicity}_{\text{of }\lambda}\big(AB\big) $

in other words: *all positive eigenvalues of* $\big(AB\big)$ *are semi-simple*

**semisimplicity of** $\lambda =0$
underlying ideas in the below inequalities (i) submultiplicativity of rank which holds over any field, (ii) usefulness of matrix square root which is something of a special feature in $\mathbb R$ or $\mathbb C$ associated with positive semi-definiteness, (iii) in $\mathbb R$ or $\mathbb C$ we have
$\text{rank}\big(Z^*Z\big) = \text{rank}\big(Z\big)$ and $\text{rank}\big(Z^*Z\big)=\text{rank}\big(ZZ^*\big)$
for a crude proof of (iii): use Polar Decomposition

To prove that zero is semisimple-- or equivalently, to prove that there isn't a 'shortage' of eigenvectors associated with the eigenvalue $0$, we need to estimate $(AB)$'s  rank

$\text{rank}\big(AB\big)$
$=\text{rank}\big(B^*A^*AB\big)$
$=\text{rank}\big(BA^2B\big)$
$\leq\text{rank}\big(B^\frac{1}{2}A^2B\big)$
$\leq\text{rank}\big(B^\frac{1}{2}A^2B^\frac{1}{2}\big)$
$=\text{rank}\big(ABA\big)$
$\leq\text{rank}\big(A^\frac{1}{2}BA\big)$
$\leq\text{rank}\big(A^\frac{1}{2}BA^\frac{1}{2}\big)$

If we negate the above and add $n$ we can apply rank-nullity to get
$\text{algebraic multiplicity}_{\text{of }\lambda \text{= 0}}\big(A^\frac{1}{2}BA^\frac{1}{2}\big)$
$=\text{geometric multiplicity}_{\text{of }\lambda \text{= 0}}\big(A^\frac{1}{2}BA^\frac{1}{2}\big) $
$\leq \text{geometric multiplicity}_{\text{of }\lambda \text{= 0}}\big(AB\big) $
$\leq \text{algebraic multiplicity}_{\text{of }\lambda \text{= 0}}\big(AB\big) $
$=\text{algebraic multiplicity}_{\text{of }\lambda \text{= 0}}\big(A^\frac{1}{2}BA^\frac{1}{2}\big)$

that is, we have
$\text{geometric multiplicity}_{\text{of }\lambda \text{= 0}}\big(AB\big)= \text{algebraic multiplicity}_{\text{of }\lambda \text{= 0}}\big(AB\big) $

so we also know the eigenvalue of $0$ is semi-simple for $\big(AB\big)$, which  completes the proof.

Comment: How is rank $(ABA)= $ rank $( B^{1/2} A^2 B^{1/2} ) $. ?

Comment: @BalasubramannyanS define $Z:=B^\frac{1}{2}A$ as stated under (iii) we know $\text{rank}\big(Z^*Z\big)=\text{rank}\big(ZZ^*\big)$

Answer (score 0):

For my own reference, here is a proof modified from user8675309's excellent answer.

If $A$ is nonsingular, then $AB$ is similar to $A^{1/2}BA^{1/2}$ and hence it is diagonalisable.

If $A$ is singular, the minimal polynomial of $A^{1/2}BA^{1/2}$ will be in the form of $f(x)=xg(x)$ for some polynomial $g$. Since $(AB)(AB)^k=A^{1/2}(A^{1/2}BA^{1/2})^kA^{1/2}B$ for every $k\ge0$, we have
$$
ABf(AB)=A^{1/2}\,f(A^{1/2}BA^{1/2})\,A^{1/2}B=0.
$$
Now, for any vector $v$, let $x=g(AB)v$ and $y=B^{1/2}x$. Then
$$
(AB)^2x=(AB)^2g(AB)v=ABf(AB)v=0
$$
and we can make the following series of inferences:
\begin{aligned}
(AB)^2x=0
&\Rightarrow \left(B^{1/2}AB^{1/2}\right)^2y=0\\
&\Rightarrow B^{1/2}AB^{1/2}y=0\\
&\Rightarrow A^{1/2}B^{1/2}y=0\\
&\Rightarrow ABx=A^{1/2}(A^{1/2}B^{1/2}y)=0.\\
\end{aligned}
It follows that $f(AB)v=ABg(AB)v=ABx=0$. Since $v$ is arbitrary, $f$ must annihilate $AB$. As $f$ is the minimal polynomial of the positive semidefinite (hence diagonalisable) matrix $A^{1/2}BA^{1/2}$, it is a product of distinct linear factors. The minimal polynomial of $AB$, which divides the annihilating polynomial $f$, must therefore also be a product of distinct linear factors. Hence $AB$ is diagonalisable. Furthermore, as $AB$ has the same spectrum as $A^{1/2}BA^{1/2}$, the two products are similar to each other.