# How to prove product of positive definite matrices are diagonalizable?

Tags: linear-algebra, diagonalization, positive-definite

I'm trying to solve a problem and need to prove that product of two positive definite matrices is diagonalizable.

I know matrices are diagonalizable when they are symmetric. How do I prove that product of 2 positive definite matrices is symmetric?

thanks!

Comment: The product of two symmetric matrices need not be symmetric if they do not commute. See this answer: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/79193 $A$ and $B$ are both symmetric and positive definite, but $AB$ is not even symmetric.

Comment: To add to Cameron's comment, see also [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/113842/81360)

Comment: thank you for the information!

Comment: for a slightly more general result:  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3621512/a-and-b-are-real-symmetric-and-positive-semi-definite-matrices-of-the-same-orde/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $A,B$ are positive definite and $A^{1/2}$ denotes the (unique) positive definite square root of $A$, then $AB$ is similar to $A^{1/2}BA^{1/2}$, which is symmetric. Because $A^{1/2}BA^{1/2}$ is diagonalizable, $AB$ must be diagonalizable as well.

Comment: Oh this is clever. I like it. It took me a second to realize that *similar* is the key here, not necessarily unitarily equivalent (and I suspect they aren't unless $A$ and $B$ commute).

Comment: @CameronWilliams Of course they can't be unitarily equivalent in that case: anything orthogonally/unitarily similar to a symmetric/Hermitian matrix must be symmetric/Hermitian itself, and for this problem $AB$ is symmetric if and only if $A,B$ commute.

Comment: Does this proof apply to general positive definite A, B not being symmetric as well because it is similar instead of equivalent?

Comment: @MSquare It does not. Non-symmetric positive definite matrices $A$ will not necessarily have a positive definite square root, and the fact that $A^{1/2}BA^{1/2}$ is symmetric relies on the symmetry of $B$.

Comment: Is there any way to prove this for general positive definite A and B as well?

Comment: @MSquare I doubt that it is true without the assumption that $A,B$ are symmetric. If there is a way, then I don't know about it.

Comment: got it! thank you!