# Proof involving orthogonally diagonalizable matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, proof-writing, orthogonal-matrices

Question:

Let $A$ and $B$ be $n$ x $n$ matrices such that both A and B are orthogonally diagonalizable. Prove or disprove the following assertions:

(i) the matrix $AB$ is orthogonally diagonalizable;

(ii) the matrix $AB+BA$ is orthogonally diagonalizable.

I think I'll be using the property that $A=MTM^{-1}=MTM^T$ and same for $B$, but not really sure where to go from there? TIA.

Comment: with orthoganally diagonalizable you mean that are ortogonal and diagonalizable matrix? In this case, the eigenvalues are only $1$ and $-1$ (in $\mathbb{R}$)

Comment: you wrote $A=M T M^T$  where $T$ is diagonal. It necessarily has real eigenvalues so $A$ is symmetric.  Take a look at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3621512/a-and-b-are-real-symmetric-and-positive-semi-definite-matrices-of-the-same-orde/ then conclude you should come up with a counter example where $A$ is PSD but $B$ is indefinite (i.e. has positive and negative eigenvalues).   Focus on the $2\times 2$ case for your counterexample.